# Why is this ice so stubborn?

Tags: everyday-life, ice, freezing

In central India summers are extremely hot. So in order to stay hydrated we (a.k.a. me and a couple of friends) have been advised to carry with ourselves a refresher (which is basically a flavored ORS solution along with a bunch of vitamins and minerals.)

However what I also tend to do is sometimes put the energy drink solution in the ice tray to make *energy ice-cream*

Coming to the question I have noticed that this energy-ice is much more harder to get out the tray than normal ice. Why is it so ?

**Link to the image:** [the orange ice is the energy one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9VuOqoTUSWwMnVncE8xSklUZWs/view?usp=sharing)

As you may notice from the Image that at some places the ice has an orangish tinge (The tray on the right). Although these areas were filled with normal water ice the small amount of energy ice which remained stuck gives rise to the faint orange color seen.

Comment: Why on physics SE this question has no answer or even general comments till now ? If this question due to some reason is not suitable for this site please direct me to a page where I can request answers to this question.

Comment: Likely related: [Which would melt faster on the sidewalk, equal volumes of snow or ice?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/320443/52937)

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include what the ice looks like vs the energy drink ice?

Comment: Have put another batch in the freezer. Will upload the pictures after the ice is ready

Comment: Hi Suhrid Mulay. Linking to private clouds, dropbox, etc, is for various reasons not acceptable on SE, cf. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/2451) meta post.